# Always getting "(0 , _reactDom.h) is not a function" or "h is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

So I'm currently working on an app that utilizes electron, react, redux and some other technologies. 
For now, I only included electron, react, electron-compile and babel in the project. Redux is installed but not really configured yet.

So when I try to load the App I always get an error saying:

> index.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined

So I read a little bit online and found out that some people using preact had a similar problem. He solved it by importing h.
So after some thinking, I imported h from react-dom, and indeed, I got a different error message.

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactDom.h) is not a function

ESLint didn't show any errors about h being not resolved, so it seems to exist, but nevertheless, I'm kinda stuck here, because I can't seem to find where that his coming from

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, h } from 'react-dom';
import {Demopage} from './demopage'};
render(<Demopage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My index.html has a div with the id root on it. And calls index.js as a script.

demopage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Startpage extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>Demopage</h1>
    );
  }
}
export default Startpage;
```

So I would expect electron to display an h1 tag reading Demopage, but I only get the error messages and a white Screen.

Kind regards,
Herr Frodo

Comment: use the default export: `import Demopage from './demopage';

Comment: ReactDOM doesn't have `h` export. Why do you need it and why did you decide there's one?

Comment: Because otherwise I get the `index.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined` error.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `h` from `react-dom` import

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: Then I'll get the error `index.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still looking for a solution. If you are (or anyone else is), you might want to take a look at your .babelrc file (at the root of your project folder). Its contents should be something like this -

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Initially I was encountering a similar error message because my project was setup for Preact and its .babelrc contained a reference to @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx instead - which seems to be valid for Preact projects only.

Let me know if the above snippet solves your issue. Good luck!

Comment: Same thing here. Project had references to Preact setup and removing `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately went with parcel, because it isn't that much harder to setup and works with Babel 7.
I think the error was with babel transpilling my react stuff to preact, still not absolutely sure.